# ADODB.Connection Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: sql, vba

Disclaimer - I do not have access to write the SQL code below as a procedure, otherwise I would do so.

Trying to run the following VBA Code to pull back SQL Data and am having an issue of

> "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed".

This ONLY occurs when there are no results found. It works perfectly fine when there are results. Below is my code.

```vb
Public Sub Start_Rate()

     Dim sSQL As String
     Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, rs1 As ADODB.Recordset, iCols As Integer

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Set cn = db_Connect.GetQPSConnection

     ''''pull in sponsor
     sSQL = "SELECT t1.[spsr_full_nm] " & _
       "FROM [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[sponsor_t] t1 " & _
       "join [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[case_t] t2 on t2.spsr_id = t1.spsr_id " & _
       "where t2.case_id = '" & Range("case_id") & "'"
     Set rs = cn.Execute(sSQL)
     If rs.EOF = False Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(5, 2).CopyFromRecordset rs

     ''''pull in sequence number
     sSQL = "SELECT max(cplnd_seq_num) FROM [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].case_plan_design_t where case_id = '" & 
     Range("case_id") & "' and plndsg_rating_stat_cd = 'Complete' and bengp_cd = 'LIFE'"
     Set rs3 = cn.Execute(sSQL)
     If rs3.EOF = False Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs3

     ''''pull in rate data
     sSQL = "set nocount on; Drop Table IF Exists dbo.##Premium create table ##premium (Upper_Band 
     varchar(255), Policy_Holder_Type varchar(255), Sequence_num int, Quote_Rate decimal(5,3), Deductions 
     int) declare @columns nvarchar(max) = '' declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '' " & _
     "insert into ##premium (Upper_Band, Policy_Holder_Type, Sequence_num, Quote_Rate, Deductions) " & _
     "SELECT 'Comp Group Rate','Employee Life',[cmpgrp_rt_dsc],[cmpgrp_quot_rt],[cmpgrp_rt_guar_mos_num] 
     FROM [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[rr_composite_group_rate_t] " & _
       "where case_id = '" & Range("case_id") & "' and cplnd_seq_num = '" & Range("Seq_Num") & "' and 
     ben_cd like '%LFE%' and ben_cd like '%EMP%' " & _
     "insert into ##premium (Upper_Band, Policy_Holder_Type, Sequence_num, Quote_Rate, Deductions) " & _
     "SELECT 'Comp Group Rate','Spouse Life',[cmpgrp_rt_dsc],[cmpgrp_quot_rt],[cmpgrp_rt_guar_mos_num] 
     FROM [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[rr_composite_group_rate_t] " & _
       "where case_id = '" & Range("case_id") & "' and cplnd_seq_num = '" & Range("Seq_Num") & "' and 
     ben_cd like '%LFE%' and ben_cd like '%SPS%' " & _
     "insert into ##premium (Upper_Band, Policy_Holder_Type, Sequence_num, Quote_Rate, Deductions) " & _
     "SELECT 'Comp Group Rate','Child Life',[cmpgrp_rt_dsc],[cmpgrp_quot_rt],[cmpgrp_rt_guar_mos_num] 
     FROM [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[rr_composite_group_rate_t] " & _
       "where case_id = '" & Range("case_id") & "' and cplnd_seq_num = '" & Range("Seq_Num") & "' and 
     ben_cd like '%LFE%' and ben_cd like '%DEP%' or case_id = '" & Range("case_id") & "' and 
     cplnd_seq_num = '" & Range("Seq_Num") & "' and ben_cd like '%LFE%' and ben_cd like '%CH%' " & _
     "insert into ##premium (Upper_Band, Policy_Holder_Type, Sequence_num, Quote_Rate, Deductions) " & _
     "SELECT 'Comp Group Rate','BASIC Life',[cmpgrp_rt_dsc],[cmpgrp_quot_rt],[cmpgrp_rt_guar_mos_num] 
     FROM [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[rr_composite_group_rate_t] " & _
       "where case_id = '" & Range("case_id") & "' and cplnd_seq_num = '" & Range("Seq_Num") & "' and 
     ben_cd like '%LFE%' and ben_cd like 'BASIC%' " & _
     "insert into ##premium (Upper_Band, Policy_Holder_Type, Sequence_num, Quote_Rate, Deductions) " & _
     "SELECT 'Comp Group Rate','OPT Life',[cmpgrp_rt_dsc],[cmpgrp_quot_rt],[cmpgrp_rt_guar_mos_num] FROM 
     [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[rr_composite_group_rate_t] " & _
       "where case_id = '" & Range("case_id") & "' and cplnd_seq_num = '" & Range("Seq_Num") & "' and 
     ben_cd like '%LFE%' and ben_cd like 'OPT%' " & _
     "select @columns = stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename(Policy_Holder_Type) from ##premium for xml 
     path(''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') " & _
     "set @sql = 'set nocount on; select Upper_Band, ' + @columns + ', Deductions from (select 
     Upper_Band, Policy_Holder_Type, Quote_Rate, Deductions from ##premium) x pivot(sum(Quote_Rate) for 
     Policy_Holder_Type in ('+ @columns +')) as pvt;'; execute sp_executesql @sql "
     Set rs1 = cn.Execute(sSQL)
     For iCols = 0 To rs1.Fields.Count - 1
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(13, iCols + 1).Value = rs1.Fields(iCols).Name
     Next
     If rs1.EOF = False Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(14, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs1


     Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you should try a `.MoveNext` pattern: https://devguru.com/content/technologies/ado/recordset-movenext.html

Comment: Where is your `cn.Open` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You need a guard clause to check `rs1` before you use it.

> If you open a Recordset object containing no records, the BOF and EOF properties are set to True, and the Recordset object's RecordCount property setting is 0

EXAMPLE:

```
Set rs1 = cn.Execute(sSQL)
If Not (rs1.EOF And rs1.BOF) Then
```

REFERENCE:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-eof-property-dao

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, consider [SQL parameterization](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) (the programming industry best practice beyond VBA but anywhere SQL is used in application layer) and avoid messy concatenation of variables into SQL statements. Parameterization can enhance readability, maintainability, even efficiency. ADO library in VBA does support [parameterization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-ver15).

For your issue, consider simplifying your dynamic pivot query to a conditional aggregation. Usually dynamic pivots are reserved for open-ended, numerous values to be pivoted into columns. However, your `INSERT INTO` queries show a manageable size at 5 pivoted columns for values: `'Employee Life', 'Spouse Life', 'Child Life', 'BASIC Life', 'OPT Life'`. With such a query, you will return an empty resultset and not issues with no results as `sp_executesql` can yield.

Specifically, replace these last three lines (with corresponding `DECLARE` at top):

```sql
select @columns = ...

set @sql = ...

execute sp_executesql @sql
```

for single `SELECT` statement:

```sql
SELECT Upper_Band
     , Deductions 
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Policy_Holder_Type = 'Employee Life' THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [Employee Life]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Policy_Holder_Type = 'Spouse Life'   THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [Spouse Life]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Policy_Holder_Type = 'Child Life'    THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [Child Life]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Policy_Holder_Type = 'BASIC Life'    THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [BASIC Life]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Policy_Holder_Type = 'OPT Life'      THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [OPT Life]
FROM ##premium
GROUP BY Upper_Band
       , Deductions
```

Actually, you can even avoid a temp table and multiple inserts by using a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) union query

```sql
WITH premium (Upper_Band, Policy_Holder_Type, Sequence_num, Quote_Rate, Deductions) 
AS 
(
   SELECT 'Comp Group Rate', 'Employee Life', [cmpgrp_rt_dsc], [cmpgrp_quot_rt], [cmpgrp_rt_guar_mos_num] 
   FROM [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[rr_composite_group_rate_t]
   WHERE case_id = ?
     AND cplnd_seq_num = ? 
     AND ben_cd LIKE '%LFE%' 
     AND ben_cd LIKE '%EMP%'

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 'Comp Group Rate', 'Spouse Life', [cmpgrp_rt_dsc], [cmpgrp_quot_rt], [cmpgrp_rt_guar_mos_num] 
   FROM [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[rr_composite_group_rate_t]
   WHERE case_id = ? 
     AND cplnd_seq_num = ? 
     AND ben_cd LIKE '%LFE%' 
     AND ben_cd LIKE '%SPS%'

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 'Comp Group Rate', 'Child Life', [cmpgrp_rt_dsc], [cmpgrp_quot_rt], [cmpgrp_rt_guar_mos_num] 
   FROM [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[rr_composite_group_rate_t]
   WHERE (case_id = ?
     AND cplnd_seq_num = ? 
     AND ben_cd LIKE '%LFE%' 
     AND ben_cd LIKE '%DEP%')
      OR (case_id = ? 
     AND cplnd_seq_num = ? 
     AND ben_cd LIKE '%LFE%' 
     AND ben_cd LIKE '%CH%')

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 'Comp Group Rate', 'BASIC Life', [cmpgrp_rt_dsc], [cmpgrp_quot_rt], [cmpgrp_rt_guar_mos_num] 
   FROM [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[rr_composite_group_rate_t]
   WHERE case_id = ? 
     AND cplnd_seq_num = ? 
     AND ben_cd LIKE '%LFE%' 
     AND ben_cd LIKE 'BASIC%'

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 'Comp Group Rate', 'OPT Life', [cmpgrp_rt_dsc], [cmpgrp_quot_rt], [cmpgrp_rt_guar_mos_num] 
   FROM [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[rr_composite_group_rate_t]
   WHERE case_id = ? 
     AND cplnd_seq_num = ? 
     AND ben_cd LIKE '%LFE%' 
     AND ben_cd LIKE 'OPT%'
)

SELECT Upper_Band
     , Deductions 
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Policy_Holder_Type = 'Employee Life' THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [Employee Life]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Policy_Holder_Type = 'Spouse Life'   THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [Spouse Life]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Policy_Holder_Type = 'Child Life'    THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [Child Life]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Policy_Holder_Type = 'BASIC Life'    THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [BASIC Life]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Policy_Holder_Type = 'OPT Life'      THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [OPT Life]
FROM premium
GROUP BY Upper_Band
       , Deductions
```

---

Even better, no CTE may be necessary as all can be handled in a *single* conditional aggregation since all data derive from same table. This also reduces the number of parameters to bind.

**SQL** *(with qmark `?` placeholders for parameterization)*

```sql
SELECT 'Comp Group Rate' AS Upper_Band
     , [cmpgrp_rt_guar_mos_num] AS Deductions
     , SUM(CASE WHEN  ben_cd LIKE '%LFE%' AND ben_cd LIKE '%EMP%'  THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [Employee Life]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN  ben_cd LIKE '%LFE%' AND ben_cd LIKE '%SPS%'  THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [Spouse Life]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN (ben_cd LIKE '%LFE%' AND ben_cd LIKE '%DEP%')
                  OR (ben_cd LIKE '%LFE%' AND ben_cd LIKE '%CH%')  THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [Child Life]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN  ben_cd LIKE '%LFE%' AND ben_cd LIKE 'BASIC%' THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [BASIC Life]
     , SUM(CASE WHE N ben_cd LIKE '%LFE%' AND ben_cd LIKE 'OPT%'   THEN Quote_Rate END) AS [OPT Life]
FROM [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[rr_composite_group_rate_t]
WHERE case_id = ? 
  AND cplnd_seq_num = ? 
GROUP BY [cmpgrp_rt_guar_mos_num]
```

**VBA** *(using ADODB [Command parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) for all queries)*

```vb
Public Sub Start_Rate()

     Dim sSQL As String
     Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command, rs As ADODB.Recordset
     DIm iCols As Integer

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Set cn = db_Connect.GetQPSConnection

     ''''pull in sponsor
     sSQL = "SELECT t1.[spsr_full_nm] " & _
            " FROM [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[sponsor_t] t1 " & _
            " JOIN [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].[case_t] t2 on t2.spsr_id = t1.spsr_id " & _
            " WHERE t2.case_id = ?"

     Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
     With cmd
         .ActiveConnection = cn
         .CommandText = sSQL
         .CommandType = adCmdText

         ' BIND PARAMS AND DEFINE TYPE AND LENGTH
         .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("prm", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Range("case_id"))

         ' CREATE RECORDSET
         Set rs = .Execute
     End cmd

     If rs.EOF = False Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(5, 2).CopyFromRecordset rs

     rs.Close
     Set rs = Nothing: Set cmd = Nothing
     

     ''''pull in sequence number
     sSQL = "SELECT MAX(cplnd_seq_num)" & _
            " FROM [Grpcare1_pr].[dbo].case_plan_design_t" & _
            " WHERE case_id = ?" & _
            " AND plndsg_rating_stat_cd = 'Complete' AND bengp_cd = 'LIFE'"

     Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
     With cmd
         .ActiveConnection = cn
         .CommandText = sSQL
         .CommandType = adCmdText

         ' BIND PARAMS AND DEFINE TYPE AND LENGTH
         .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("prm", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Range("case_id"))

         ' CREATE RECORDSET
         Set rs = .Execute
     End cmd

     If rs.EOF = False Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

     rs.Close
     Set rs = Nothing: Set cmd = Nothing


     ''''pull in rate data
     sSQL = "..."  ' SAME SQL QUERY AS ABOVE

     Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
     With cmd
         .ActiveConnection = cn
         .CommandText = sSQL
         .CommandType = adCmdText

         ' BIND PARAMS AND DEFINE TYPE AND LENGTH
         .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("prm1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Range("case_id"))
         .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("prm2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Range("Seq_Num"))

         ' CREATE RECORDSET
         Set rs = .Execute
     End cmd

     For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(13, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
     Next
     If rs.EOF = False Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(14, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

     rs.Close
     Set rs = Nothing: Set cmd = Nothing: Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```